# Variable scope in function closure?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've just started using nested functions and they come in very handy. However I am running into problems with populating a variable which is later returned by the enclosing function.

The code below is for an AIR project to load some `BitmapData`. I expected that my variable ("bitmapData") would be populated in the `loaderComplete` function but it is always returned as null. However, in my trace statements, the image dimensions are being logged, so clearly it has been read.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or my understanding (or both ;-)

```
        private function getBitmapData(url:String):BitmapData
        {
            var bitmapData:BitmapData;
            var bytes:ByteArray = getByteArray(url);
            if (bytes == null){
                trace("bytes null");
                return null;
            }

            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.loadBytes(bytes);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);

            function loaderComplete(event:Event):void
            {
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);
                var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
                trace("loader",loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height);
                bitmapData = new BitmapData(loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height, false, 0xFFFFFF);
                trace("bitmapData.rect", bitmapData.rect);
                bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader);
            }

            function ioErrorListener(event:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                trace("ioErrorListener", event.errorID);
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);
            }
            return bitmapData;
        }
```

---

```
        public function getByteArray(url:String):ByteArray{
            var byteFile:File = new File(url);
            if(byteFile.exists && !byteFile.isDirectory){
                var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                fileStream.open(byteFile, FileMode.READ);
                var tempBytes: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                fileStream.readBytes( tempBytes );
                fileStream.close(); 
                return tempBytes;
            } else {
                trace("file doesnt exist");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Loader.loadBytes()` is an asynchronous method. The `COMPLETE` event is not fired in the same frame as the call to `loadBytes`. Therefore, you're actually attempting to return `bitmapData` *before* the code in `loaderComplete` executes.

You may want to try doing something with callbacks. For example, you can pass a reference to a function as a parameter in `getBitmapData`, and then call that function in `loaderComplete`:

```
private function getBitmapData(url:String, callback:Function):void
{
    var bitmapData:BitmapData;
    var bytes:ByteArray = getByteArray(url);
    if (bytes == null){
        trace("bytes null");
        callback(null);
    }

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.loadBytes(bytes);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);

    function loaderComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);
        var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
        trace("loader",loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height);
        bitmapData = new BitmapData(loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height, false, 0xFFFFFF);
        trace("bitmapData.rect", bitmapData.rect);
        bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader);
        callback(bitmapData)
    }

    function ioErrorListener(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace("ioErrorListener", event.errorID);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);
    }
}     

private function handleNewBitmapData(bitmapData:BitmapData):void 
{
    trace("handled bitmapData.rect", bitmapData.rect);
}

getBitmapData("[some url]", handleNewBitmapData);
```